# Maven package error: org.apache.commons-lang does not exist (Java)

Tags: java, maven

I'm using MyEclipse to develop a really simple Java Struts project. Everything was working fine until I wanted to use the `StringUtils` class in **org.apache.commons.lang**. In MyEclipse I imported the package like

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
```

I added the Jar file for **commons-lang-2.4** to my build path. This all works fine and dandy and I get the Intellisense and no errors in Eclipse or anything. Now, when I go to do a `mvn clean package`, I get an error saying that

> The package org.apache.commons.lang does not exist

I checked in my war/Pom.xml file and I do have it declared as a dependency

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

From my research I figured that Maven should download the package and install it to my local repository if it doesn't exists. I checked the repository and the jar file was in there. I figured the jar file must be corrupted so I deleted the **commons-lang** folder to get a fresh download of commons-lang. Now this is where it blows my mind, after I deleted it from the local repository and ran a `mvn clean package`, it goes out and downloads the **commons-lang-2.1**.pom and jar (even though the pom.xml has 2.4) **BUT** still gives a compilation failure saying that *the package org.apache.commons.lang does not exist*.

I haven't been using Maven for very long so I'm not sure how to go about fixing this. Am I missing something? Do I need to add the dependency in another pom.xml file somewhere else?

Comment: Not sure if there was file corruption or what, but after confirming dependencies via @TomaszNurkiewicz's method I was able to resolve this issue by deleting the jar from my local m2 repository when I ran the tests.

Comment: First, I deleted commons-lang in repository, and it worked.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Try running the following commands and examine the output:

```
$ mvn dependency:tree
$ mvn help:effective-pom
```

Look for `commons-lang`, maybe something will draw your attention like excludes or dependency overrides. Also, is:

```
$ mvn dependency:copy-dependencies
```

copying `commons-lang` JAR to your `target`?

Comment: Thanks that helped a bunch! I added a reference for the commons-lang 2.4 to my jar pom.xml and now it works. I closed and reopened command prompt before doing the clean package and then it downloaded the correct versions of the jars and built successfully. Should've posted this question hours ago. Thanks

Comment: What command prompt we are talking about here? I am using netbeans on windows 8

Answer (score 27):

Adding following dependency to pom.xml in dependencies tag helped me:

```
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 7):

I did `mvn clean install -U` without `settings.xml`, so it erred.

Then I added `settings.xml`, did `mvn clean install -U`, it said `error:org.apache.commons-lang does not exist`.

I know the code was built successfully on another machine. So it was not my code.

After about 2 or 3 hours, I finally realized it was `.m2\repository` was corrupted by my first run.

So just delete `repository` folder complete and run `mvn clean install -U` and succeeded.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following in the pom.xml

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
<version>3.12.0</version>
</dependency>
```

and make sure that your Java code has this import entry
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
NOT import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

Please pay attention to lang3 that makes the difference out here.

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced the same Issue. I tried all the approaches but what I did at last is downloaded the jar file and extracted. In intelliJ, Files > projectStructure > libraries. Click on the plus symbol and the extracted jar file there. I worked as wonder.

Answer (score -11):

In src/main/java there would be a .auth folder. Open the folder, Go to AuthController.java file and delete the import io.swagger line. Restart.