# Jenkins Error:- [ERROR] error reading /home/oci/.m2/repository/org/apache-extras/beanshell/bsh/2.0b6/bsh-2.0b6.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins

I have created a maven project and try to run it with Jenkins.

Below is my Jenkins error:-

I am learning how to run a maven project in Jenkins but Jenkins has given me this error(invalid LOC header (bad signature)) do I need to add the dependency for this also.
but I already did that and still, I am facing this issue.
I have commented on some of the plugins.
There are more error in Jenkins, check that too, please

```
Executing Maven:  -B -f /home/oci/git/Maven_First_Project/com.first_maven/pom.xml clean install
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] ---------------------< com.code_maven:maven_first >---------------------
    [INFO] Building com.maven_first 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    [INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ maven_first ---
    [INFO] Deleting /home/oci/git/Maven_First_Project/com.first_maven/target
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ maven_first ---
    [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
    [INFO] Copying 0 resource
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ maven_first ---
    [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
    [INFO] Compiling 7 source files to /home/oci/git/Maven_First_Project/com.first_maven/target/classes
    [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
    [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] error reading /home/oci/.m2/repository/org/apache-extras/beanshell/bsh/2.0b6/bsh-2.0b6.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
    [ERROR] /home/oci/git/Maven_First_Project/com.first_maven/src/main/java/com/all_data_page/Online_Booking.java:[6,29] package org.apache.commons.io does not exist
    [ERROR] /home/oci/git/Maven_First_Project/com.first_maven/src/main/java/com/all_data_page/Online_Booking.java:[34,16] cannot find symbol
      symbol:   variable FileUtils
      location: class com.all_data_page.Online_Booking
    [INFO] 3 errors 
    [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time:  12.437 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2019-10-23T17:54:38+05:30
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project maven_first: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
    [ERROR] error reading /home/oci/.m2/repository/org/apache-extras/beanshell/bsh/2.0b6/bsh-2.0b6.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
    [ERROR] /home/oci/git/Maven_First_Project/com.first_maven/src/main/java/com/all_data_page/Online_Booking.java:[6,29] package org.apache.commons.io does not exist
    [ERROR] /home/oci/git/Maven_First_Project/com.first_maven/src/main/java/com/all_data_page/Online_Booking.java:[34,16] cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] symbol:   variable FileUtils
    [ERROR] location: class com.all_data_page.Online_Booking
    [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
    [JENKINS] Archiving /home/oci/git/Maven_First_Project/com.first_maven/pom.xml to com.code_maven/maven_first/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven_first-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
    /home/oci/git/Maven_First_Project/com.first_maven/pom.xml is not inside /home/oci/.jenkins/workspace/Testing_maven/home/oci/git/Maven_First_Project/com.first_maven/; will archive in a separate pass
    ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
    java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /home/oci/.jenkins/workspace/Testing_maven/home/oci/git/Maven_First_Project/com.first_maven/pom.xml
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:92)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:116)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:215)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:370)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:421)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newInputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:420)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Files.java:155)
        at hudson.FilePath.read(FilePath.java:1942)
        at jenkins.plugins.maveninfo.extractor.properties.PomPropertiesFinder.findProperties(PomPropertiesFinder.java:50)
        at jenkins.plugins.maveninfo.extractor.MavenInfoExtractor.extract(MavenInfoExtractor.java:58)
        at jenkins.plugins.maveninfo.extractor.MavenInfoEnvironment.tearDown(MavenInfoEnvironment.java:42)
        at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:908)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:504)
        at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1838)
        at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:543)
        at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
        at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
    channel stopped
    TestNG Reports Processing: START
    Looking for TestNG results report in workspace using pattern: **/testng-results.xml
    Did not find any matching files.
    Finished: FAILURE






    This is my Pom.xml file

    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>com.code_maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven_first</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>


    <packaging>jar</packaging>

      <name>com.maven_first</name>
      <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

      <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

    </properties>

      <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                  <groupId>junit</groupId>
                  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                  <version>3.8.1</version>
                  <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>       

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
                <version>3.14.0</version>
            </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.14.3</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.14.0</version>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.9</version>
    </dependency>

      </dependencies>

      <build> 

        <plugins>

               <!--  <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
                     <configuration>
                      <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>test-output/testng-failed.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                      </suiteXmlFiles>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>  --> 

    <!--             <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.6.1</version>
      <configuration>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>  -->

             <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.19.1</version>
              <configuration>
                  <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>test-output/testng-failed.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                  </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>  

        </plugins>

    </build>

    </project>
```

Answer (score 0):

These are the main errors as below:

> [ERROR] error reading
>   /home/oci/.m2/repository/org/apache-extras/beanshell/bsh/2.0b6/bsh-2.0b6.jar;
>   invalid LOC header (bad signature)
>       [ERROR] /home/oci/git/Maven_First_Project/com.first_maven/src/main/java/com/all_data_page/Online_Booking.java:[6,29]
>   package org.apache.commons.io does not exist
>       [ERROR] /home/oci/git/Maven_First_Project/com.first_maven/src/main/java/com/all_data_page/Online_Booking.java:[34,16]
>   cannot find symbol

**Error 1:**

Go the below location

/home/oci/.m2/repository/org/apache-extras/

Delete all folder here, sometimes jar corrupts and need to download again by clean install

Source:

[Deploying Maven project throws java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32090921/deploying-maven-project-throws-java-util-zip-zipexception-invalid-loc-header-b)

**Error 2:**

[Maven package error: org.apache.commons-lang does not exist (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7339264/maven-package-error-org-apache-commons-lang-does-not-exist-java)

**Error 3:**

its may be due to incompatibility between jar version, try to find the dependencies which are not compatible